# Read a file that skip spaces, punctuation, and number from a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file but I want it to skip spaces, punctuation, and numbers. I'm kind of new to the `isspace`, `ispunct`, `isalphnum` variables. to the code as follow:

```
ifstream datafile("test.txt");
while (!datafile.eof())
{
    datafile >> word;
    if (datafile.eof()) break;
    {
        it = counter.find(word);
    }
    if (it != counter.end())
    {
        it->second++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter[word] = 1;
    }
}
```

I have an idea you can use an while loop to read the file and and use the `.cstr()` for the character string but that all I know thus for.

Comment: Create a char array with every character you want to skip, look up every character you read and if found in the lookup array, skip it.

Comment: So what's the specific problem you're having? Does this code read the file, but includes spaces, punctuation and numbers?

Comment: Yea it does, I'm reading from a large file which contain varies tweets(twitter) from people